# floating action button radial menu in BottomAppBar android java

Tags: java, android, floating-action-button, bottomappbar

Respectable Gurus,
I am trying to add fab button with expandable arc / radial menu in android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar using xml and java class, after a lot of research I did not succeed.
I want the bottom bar with menu like screenshot bellow.
Any Help will be appreciated.

[image]